# Error in configuring object when converting intoTika using Behemoth and map reduce

Tags: hadoop, apache-tika, behemoth

I am running the command to convert behemoth corpus to tika using map reduce as given in [this tutorial](http://searchhub.org/2012/03/05/scaling-solr-indexing-with-solrcloud-hadoop-and-behemoth/)

I am getting following error on doing it:

```
    13/02/25 14:44:00 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/02/25 14:44:01 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201302251222_0017
13/02/25 14:44:02 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/02/25 14:44:09 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201302251222_0017_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)
attempt_201302251222_0017_m_000001_0: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient).
attempt_201302251222_0017_m_000001_0: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
13/02/25 14:44:14 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201302251222_0017_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

I am not able to understand the exact problem.What could be the possible reasons?Do i need to add copy any jar from Behemoth/Tika to hadoop working directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
The procedure, as described on this [page](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/digitalpebble/Gx5VZEB36yI) has helped me.
After I run "mvn clean install", the tika job worked as described in the tutorial.

Comment: But what exactly could the problem be, because when using the same versions and in fact the same compiled Behemoth on another system its working fine.The difference is that i installed behemoth on the latter pc and copied it to the former as the former has restricted access and cant access mvn.Can this be anyways related?thing is that i m able to generate behemoth corpus in former too

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you mentioned is outdated. See [tutorial on wiki](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/behemoth/wiki/tutorial) which is the reference.
The logs don't give any useful information as to what the problem can be but all you'd need to get Behemoth working is the job files for each module. If you have Hadoop running on a server simply use the Hadoop command on the job files or for simplicity use the [behemoth script](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/behemoth/blob/master/behemoth). 
BTW the [DigitalPebble mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/digitalpebble) would be a better place to ask questions about Behemoth

HTH

Julien